# Could individual files on a USB flash drive be deleted or damaged due to physical drop?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My flash drive fell from my pocket. It appears to still be working normally. Is it possible for one of the files to be deleted, corrupted or damaged due to the fall?

Comment: A flash device has no moving parts.  What exactly is your concern?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was just worried because I have a few unsorted important files in the USB so I was worried one of them might get deleted. But if it's impossible for just one file to get deleted from shock then I have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @nonowaimas Flash drives are pretty indestructible. I have some that have made a few rounds in the washing machine/dryer and one lost the plastic casing to it.

Comment: Likely or not, I'd never store *the only* copy of any data on a flash drive - the old adage, "Any data stored in less than 3 separate locations ought to be considered temporary"

Answer (score 1):

Extremely unlikely.  Flash memory is extremely shock resistant.  In the past, older types of memory, like EPROM, *could* lose data due to a large shock, but even that was rare.  Modern flash memory is extremely resilient.

Answer (score 0):

Flash drives are not nearly as fragile as hard drives.  Unless the PCB is cracked or the connector snapped off or bent, the drive should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely. I have had same things over and over. Even I washed my flash drive with my pants and I did not loose single fine. If it is connecting and detecting perfectly then you should be fine. 
One file cannot be deleted or misplaced. If something get broken or tore on PCB then you might loose it otherwise you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I've had a couple of abused drives break because they didn't use solid-state components. 
[image: usb-NAND-flash-memory-pen-drive-pcba-components-diagram-specs-resonator-controller.jpg]
*Image:  [Zakir Hosen](http://www.myusbtools.com/2013/06/basic-introduction-of-usb-flash-drive.html)*

See those two connections on the item labeled **quartz resonator**? Those can break off.